# How to pad text in a TextBox?

Tags: c#

The code below is a method of a Windows Forms Application which displays the times tables in textBox_TT. I want the times tables to be aligned horizontally (the user is supposed to scroll horizontally to see them all).

In order achieve the horizontal alignment, I decided to append to formattedOutput the first line of each times table and separate them with two tabs (i.e. "1 x 1 = 1 [\t\t] 2 x 1 = 2 [\t\t] 3 x 1 = 3 ..."). When I reach the last times table (e.g. "... 1 x 10 = 10") I append a carriage return and a new line character (\r\n) to create a new line. Then I append the next row of the times tables to the StringBuilder (i.e. " 1 x 2 = 2 [\t\t] 2 x 2 = 4 ...") and add the "\r\n". I do this until I have completed the times tables.

The problem is that the 10 times table isn't aligned properly (vertically). [This image shows the misalignment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jiz5P.png). Generally speaking, is there a way to pad text within a TextBox so that string length doesn't mess up the padding?

```
    private void button_displayTT_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Initialize 2D array with the values requiered for the times tables.
        int[,] numbers = new int[2, 10] {
            { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 },
            { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 }
        };
        StringBuilder formattedOutput = new StringBuilder("");

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < 10; ++j)
            {
                formattedOutput.Append($"{numbers[0, j]} x {numbers[1, i]} = {numbers[0, j] * numbers[1, i]}\t\t");
            }
            formattedOutput.Append("\r\n");
        }

        textBox_TT.Text = formattedOutput.ToString();
    }
```

Note: I know that the 2D array is completely unnecessary, I wanted to use it though.

Comment: Why a TextBox? From your screenshot, it looks like a ListBox with GridView,  DataGrid or DataGridView is better suited for your purposes...

Comment: Set the textbox font to a fixed pitch font. IE Consolas, Terminal

Comment: looks like,from image, that once counter goes to 10, it takes one more space hence pushing the next item a space as well, either print all numbers in 2 characters (01, 02 etc) or append a space to the end of each line in each table...I think that will resolve your issue, however this may be done in a better way as mentioned above using some other control

Comment: It appears to me that you need only one tab when the size of the data in the column is greater than  9 (approximately; you need to determine with certainty). So in your inner loop, use formattedOutput.Append to generate a string then append one or two tabs depending on the size of the string.